# I am attempting to locate DrugID or DCode information

Tags: openfda

Does anyone know where to obtain DCodes or DrugIDs in the OPEN FDA product? I get practically everything I need except this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [NDC Directory](https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/ndc/).